# Resize function for responsive d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I am trying to make my d3 multi-series line chart responsive follwoing this [reference](http://eyeseast.github.io/visible-data/2013/08/28/responsive-charts-with-d3/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/eyeseast/6407300) is the full code of this reference.

I add the following `resize` function to the bottom of [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/lszhou2115/hnce2n2r/7/):

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {

    //update width
    var main_width = parseInt(d3.select('#myChart').style('width'), 10);
    main_width = main_width - main_margin.left - main_margin.right;

    //resize the chart
    main_x.range([0, main_width]);
    mini_x.range([0, main_width]);

    d3.select('#myChart').append("svg")
    .attr("width", main_width + main_margin.left + main_margin.right)
    .attr("height", main_height + main_margin.top + main_margin.bottom);

    svg.selectAll('defs.clipPath.rect')
    .attr("width", main_width);

    svg.selectAll('rect.overlay')
    .attr("width", main_width);

}).trigger("resize");
```

But nothing is changed when I adjust the screen. No idea why, please advise!
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just detect all svg elements and attributes that have something to do with width `main_width`, because responsive mean the width will be adjusted when screen resize.

here is the `resize()` function that works well:

```
//----------- responsive d3, resize functionality -----------
$(window).on("resize", function() {

  //update width
  main_width = parseInt(d3.select('#myChart').style('width'), 10);
  main_width = main_width - main_margin.left - main_margin.right;

  //resize main and min time axis range
  main_x.range([0, main_width]);
  mini_x.range([0, main_width]);

  //pointpoint the 'rect' element about brush functionality and adjust its width
  svg.selectAll('rect.brushrect').attr("width", main_width);

  //pinpoint the 'rect' element about mousemove and adjust its width
  svg.selectAll('rect.overlay').attr("width", main_width);

  //update x axis
  svg.selectAll("g.x.axis").transition().call(main_xAxis);

  //update right y axis
  svg.selectAll('g.y.axisRight').attr("transform", "translate(" + main_width + ", 0)").call(main_yAxisRight);

  // update main line0 and line4
  svg.selectAll("path.line.line0").datum(data).transition().attr("d", main_line0);
  svg.selectAll("path.line.line4").datum(data).transition().attr("d", main_line4);

  //update min line0 and line4
  mini.selectAll("path.mini_line0").datum(data).transition().attr("d", mini_line0);
  mini.selectAll("path.mini_line4").datum(data).transition().attr("d", mini_line4);

}).trigger("resize");
```

Two things to note

- The `rect` attribute with respect to brushing, i.e,

  svg.append("defs")
  .append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", main_width)
  .attr("height", main_height);

does not have a *name*, so the following `class` attribute should be added for pinpointing:

```
.attr('class', "brushrect")
```

- The `class` for mini lines are changed to `mini_line0` and `mini_line4`, some the codes have some tiny update related to that.

then all done.